# How to get each track of a playlist with the Soundcloud API?

Tags: javascript, api, stream, soundcloud

I am working with the Soundcloud API to create a custom playlist (another look than the original Soundcloud player). See image below. I am develop a website for an artist.

With the API of Soundcloud I want to import his music from Soundcloud to the website. There are different tabs that should represents all albums - you can see this on the picture - that are uploaded in the SC database. This I have done with the following code:

```
SC.get('/users/' + USER + '/playlists', function(playlists) {
    $(playlists).each(function(index, playlist) {
    $('h2').html(playlist.title);

    $('.list-of-links').append($('<li></li>').html('<a href="#">' + playlist.title + '</a>'));
//$('#cover').append($('<li></li>').css('background-image', "url('" + track.artwork_url + "')");
    $("#cover").append('<div><img src="' + playlist.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t500x500') + '"></div>');

    });
    });
```

Where `USER` is a global variable where the name "mo-rooneh" is stored in.

[image]

So that's working correct. Now I want to get from each album, (1) the album title and (2) all the tracks of that album, that contains a start and stop button to play each track and the amount of likes listed in a `UL` list. I don't know how to achieve this. What I have now is that the code returns the album title and all tracks of the user. Know it posts for each album all tracks of the user, so also tracks from other albums. What I want is that it will show me the tracks of that specific album:

```
SC.connect(function() {

        SC.get('/users/' + USER + '/playlists', function(playlists) {

            $(playlists).each(function(index, playlist) {

                SC.get('/users/' + USER + '/tracks', function(tracks) {

                    $('.test').append($('<h2></h2>').html('<a href="#">' + playlist.title + '</a>'));

                    $(tracks).each(function(index, track) {
                        $('.test').append($('<p></p>').html('<a href="#">' + track.title + '</a>'));

                    });

                });


            });

        });
    });
```

I look out for your answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soundcloud's developer docs state that each playlist contains an array of tracks (see https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists).

You should be able to loop through the array and populate the html with the relevant values by effectively joining the code in your question together, though you will want to either use classes in the markup or generate individual IDs for each playlist (maybe something like `"playlist"+playlist.id`).

**FURTHER EDIT**: Updated to include a containing object to access methods for each track by ID reference.

```
var track_objects = {};

SC.get('/users/' + USER + '/playlists', function(playlists) {

  $(playlists).each(function(index, playlist) {

    // Let's say you have divs with class 'playlist', adhering to the structure of the markup you imply in your question.
    // Store reference to the current playlist
    var $playlist = $('.playlist').eq(index);
    // Populate with values
    $playlist.find('h2').html(playlist.title);
    $playlist.find('.list-of-links').append($('<li></li>').html('<a href="#">' + playlist.title + '</a>'));
    $playlist.find('.cover').append('<div><img src="' + playlist.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t500x500') + '"></div>');

    // Maybe you would have a ul in each of your playlist divs with a class of tracks...
    // Store reference to the track ul
    var $tracks = $playlist.find('ul.tracks');

    $(playlist.tracks).each(function(i, track) { // Use 'i' so there's no conflict with 'index' of parent loop

      // Your count var is unnecessary, i is 0-indexed so just add 1 to get the track number
      // Note use of track.id here, and different classes for start / stop
      $tracks.append($('<li data-id="' + track.id + '"></li>').html('<a href="#" class="start">Start</a> / <a href="#" class="stop">Stop</a>' + (i + 1) + ' / ' + track.title + ' - ' + track.playback_count));

    });

  });

});
```

**EDIT:**

Glad it's working for you (I've been working in vanilla JS for a while so my jQuery is a little rusty...)

To stream a sound, all you need to do is assign an event listener to the `<a/>` element, grab the track id from the `data-attribute` of the parent node, and call `SC.stream` with the id variable - see example below (also see https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#streaming).

(**Note:** changes are required to the code above - use track.id in the data-attribute as Soundcloud's API works with the id rather than the title, and you'll want appropriate classes for start/stop buttons).

**EDITED THRICE**: Check to see if the sound object has been stored already - if so, simply call `play()` on the stored object without needing to reinstantiate the Soundcloud streaming object.

```
// Depending on jQuery version, you may need 'live()' here
$('a.start').on('click', function(){

  var track_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

  if( typeof track_objects[track_id] !== 'undefined' ){
    // We already have this one, no need to make another call to SC.stream
    var sound = track_objects[track_id];
    sound.play();
  }else{
    // First play requested - we need to load this one
    SC.stream('/tracks/' + track_id, function(sound){
      sound.play();
      // Store sound object
      track_objects[track_id] = sound;
    });
  }

});
// Depending on jQuery version, you may need 'live()' here
$('a.stop').on('click', function(){

  var track_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

  // In case a user clicks stop accidentally on a track that hasn't been played yet, check for undefined here too
  if( typeof track_objects[track_id] !== 'undefined' ){
    var sound = track_objects[track_id];
    sound.stop();
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working. One question, do you also know how to play each track individual?

Comment: See above, edited to include streaming. I hope the stop button works, I stored each sound object in part of a mini-library I wrote when I built my site and so could call it's methods from anywhere.

Comment: The part to stop the track with playing doesn't work. It keep going playing the song.. How can I do this on another methode?

Comment: Try that - note the changes to both code blocks, I could have made it clearer but typing code on my phone keyboard is kinda painful!

Comment: You could also check to see if the sound object is undefined before calling the stream method - if it's been streamed once you'll already have it in the containing object.

Comment: I tried above updated lines, but it will give me an error: `GET https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/undefined/stream?oauth_token=1-134687-9095247-22677873f6a2681 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Just copy paste your code above. And is there a possibility to bypass the connect pop-up while refreshing?

Comment: The stop function doesn't perform a GET request, the url you pasted above is requesting 'undefined' as a track id so there must be something changed in the start handler... Does it give you the error immediately on requesting stream?

Comment: Sorry just realised that wouldn't work because of dot syntax, see edit above - still shouldn't be performing a GET request though, and track id shouldn't be undefined when requesting stream (this was working for you before, correct?)

Comment: Just saw what you said about the connect popup - don't authenticate! You only need that for users to sign in or perform PUT / POST / DELETE operations, streaming is fine with a client id only

Comment: Thank you. I will try above code tomorrow! Do you mean by not authenticate, make no use of clientID and redirect_uri?

Comment: Right, that should be everything! Just ran it on my system and pulled down all of my playlists/tracks fine - start/stop fully working too. As for authentication, Soundcloud effectively uses two "layers" - the first is with the client ID, this is necessary for calling anything from the SDK. The second is for *the end user*, so they can interact with your app / website via Soundcloud, and is not required for streaming. Basically pass client ID, don't pass redirect_uri.