# Building custom player with Soundcloud. Playlist organisation

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, playlist, soundmanager2

Thanks for these guys and their code([How to get each track of a playlist with the Soundcloud API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964214/how-to-get-each-track-of-a-playlist-with-the-soundcloud-api/32147808#32147808)), my playlist started working.

But I'd like to start/pause playing with pressing on song name (not different buttons).

I tried to do this with:

1. `playState` property
2. `togglePause()` method

I did not have any success with them - `playState` always shows 'undefined' in `console.log`. With second variant says -

> sound.togglePause is not a function.

Here is one of my variants of code.

```js
SC.initialize({
        client_id: "53902af7a344bb0351898c47bc3d786f"
    });

$(document).ready(function(){

    
        SC.get('/users/8179872/playlists/135665862', function(playlist) {
            
        
        $(playlist.tracks).each(function(i, track) {
            
            var $tr = $('.tr').eq(i);
            
            $tr.append((i + 1) + ' ' + track.title);
            $tr.attr('value', track.id);
      
        });
            
    $('.tr').on('click', function(){
            
       var track_id = $(this).attr('value');

       SC.stream('/tracks/' + track_id, function(sound){
        
           if (sound.playState === undefined || sound.playState === 0 || 
               sound.paused === true) {
                     sound.play();
                     console.log(sound.playState);
           } else {
                     sound.pause();
           }
    
         });

      });
        
   }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>music</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1251">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://soundmanagerv297a-20150601/script/soundmanager2.js"></script>
    <script src='scriptmine.js'></script>
    <link href="main.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="script_m">
          <ul class='pl_t'>
              <li class='tr'></li>
              <li class='tr'></li>
              <li class='tr'></li>
              <li class='tr'></li>
              <li class='tr'></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: maybe someone can check my code and have some ideas?